# How to take into the account part of condition inside the condition only if some value is true

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I'm trying to understand how it is possible to put condition inside condition itself.

for example, below I'm showing wrong unreal code, but  clear to understand what I'm asking for without extra words:

```
  if (a == 1 && if (b == 1) { c >= 5 })
  {
     /// process
  }
```

So condition `c >= 5`  must be taken into the account  for process only in case if `b == 1` which  must be exist  inside one statement without using of separate function with separate conditions or as condition after condition.

Question is how take part of condition  into the account inside the condition only in case if some value is true and avoid it if false and read only `a == 1`.

EDIT based on answer below:

```
            int a = 1;
            int b = 0;
            int c = 6;

            if (a == 1 && (b != 0 || c >= 5))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("yes");

                if (c > 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("taken into the account");
                }                   
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no");
            }
```

in both cases `int b = 1;` and `int b = 0;` result is:

```
yes
taken into the account
```

desired result:

in case of `int b = 1;` :

```
yes
taken into the account
```

and in case of `int b = 0;`:

```
 yes
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (a == 1 && (b != 1 || c >= 5 ))
```

Here, `c >= 5` will only be evaluated when `b==1`.

Comment: I am trying to understand your solution. How come its b != 1 and will only evaluate c >=5 if its under OR condition? I just want to understand your solution :)

Comment: @Eren Ersönmez Hello, I have edit my question based on your solution, and seems it is not correct for this case, but I guess now  it is  more clear to understand what I'm asking for

Comment: @rayho Your edit is incorrect. The 'taken into account' always fires because `c >= 5`. It has nothing to do with the if condition being evaluated. Your desired results state '`in the case of int b = 0 it should not print taken into account`. That's impossible, because the conditional for 'taken into account' *only* depends on `c` once it's inside the first conditional.

Comment: @ Rob Hello, yes I'm understand it, that's why I'm asking this question, my edit shows wrong way of solution, of course  it is always into the account, but also it is explains my question better, despite the fact that the condition for such solution  is completely wrong

Comment: @WillyDavidJr `||` is the _conditional_ OR operator.  If the left operand evaluates to true, it will not evaluate the right side. `|` (logical OR), on the other hand, will evaluate both sides, no matter if the left side is true or false.

Comment: @rayho In your edit example, in case of `b==1`, the expression `c >= 5` will not be evaluated.  The inner if statement, however, is independent and `c > 5` will always be evaluated (it may evaluate to true or false but it will always be evaluated). Your desired results would be achieved when `c <= 5`.

Comment: @Eren Ersönmez yes in case of `c <= 5` result is equal to desired, but it's not the same thing what I'm asking for, it is just usual result from  condition with  particular value,  and not the  avoiding of the part of exist condition in the condition itself. So it seems like it is impossible, but I'm not sure if it is really impossible in c#, maybe there is some method

Comment: @rayho I don't think I understand what you're asking for at this point. I thought you question was "how do I skip the c >= 5 condition when b == 1"? In other words, you only want to consider c>=5 when when b != 1, which is what I showed in my answer.  Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: @Eren Ersönmez simply,  in code above, which contains your condition. keep  ` int a = 1;` don't change it, its role is to fulfill whole process  or it is just some condition in process, no matter. And keep ` int c = 6;` bigger then 5, don't change it too. Change only `int b = 0;` and in case of 0 somehow skip this inner condition  `if (c >= 5)`  despite the fact that the condition is always true, but process it only if `int b = 1;` without change in condition itself this way `if (c <= 5)`

Answer (score 0):

In c# && is a short circuiting operation so b==1 will not be evaluated if a==1 does not evaluate to true.